# xcode7 archive ad-hoc ipa can't include all devices, xcode6 is good

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode7, ios-provisioning

i don't understand why xcode7 can't archive ad-hoc ipa including all devices, xcode6 is good for that.

I can make sure that my certificates is good and include all devices.

Anyone else met this problem?

Comment: do you get any errors

Comment: no, no error...eg. i have 50 devices , but just include 20 devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I'd like to share my experience in dealing with provisioning profiles.

1. We surely need to generate our provisioning profiles from Member Center of Apple Developer. After adding the user's devices (UDID), download the latest provisioning profiles to local.
2. Completely quit Xcode and drag the new provisioning profiles on the icon of Xcode. Now Xcode can find the provisioning profiles you just generated.
3. Open Xcode, and go to Xcode -> Preferences... -> Accounts -> View details..., we will see all the provisioning profiles saved on the mac. Just right-click any of them, and reveal it in Finder.
4. Look for the newest file which is the provisioning profiles we just added. We can  open provisioning profiles with any text editor in order to check `AppIDName` and which `ProvisionedDevices`are contained in it. In this way, **we can delete outdated provisioning profiles easily** in case Xcode doesn't pick the right provisioning profiles.

After archiving and exporting the .ipa file, we still can make sure whether all the user's UDID are included.

1. Rename the suffix **.ipa** to **.zip**, and now the icon should look like a normal **.zip** file.
2. Extract the **.zip** and a new folder named **Payload** appears. Open that folder and Show Content Packages, we will see an file called **embedded.mobileprovision**.
3. It is same as the provisioning profile we generated at the beginning if we have done everything correctly.

Comment: Hi, I got a problem,  I did  what you said and  repack it，I installed it in my phone, but show a error 'App installation failed .....A signed resource has been added, modified, or delete'.....How do you repack it ?

Comment: @LanceLan Have you tried to typed the error in google because the error seems to depend on different situations. And what do you mean by 'repack'?

Comment: sorry for my poor english....i don't know how to describe it， what should I do when I change the embeadded.mobileprovision.

Comment: @LanceLan You shouldn't change **embeadded.mobileprovision** in **.ipa** you generated. The steps that I followed to export an **.ipa** are: 1. Choose the correct provisioning profile in _Build settings->Code Signing_. 2. Unplug your iPhone (now the device type should display **iOS Device**). 3. _Product->Archive_ and export Ad-hoc app. Don't worry about your English, if you have any problem, just let me know :)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it didn't work,  I will upgrade the xcode to 7.0.1~~Thanks again....

Comment: @LanceLan Let me know if you either make it works or still need help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a whole bunch of issues when updating to xcode 7 and archiving. My solution was to delete all of my provisioning profiles and certificates from the member centre and create them again. Making sure i had created the correct distribution ones.

Ad-hoc uses distribution provisioning profile so make sure that is correct.